# Setting EXIT_MESSAGE in batch_job_execution

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing

One of the step in my job is having an exception and hence the job is failing with the **EXIT_CODE** "FAILED". Now I want to set the EXIT_MESSAGE as well, I did the following but the message is not getting set.. Any ideas??

```
chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().setExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED);  
ExitStatus es = jobExecution.getExitStatus();  
es = exitStatus.**addExitDescription**("CUSTOM EXCEPTION MESSAGE");
chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().setExitStatus(es);
```

I also tried the following but didn't work.
setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("FAILED","CUSTOM EXCEPTION MESSAGE"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to manipulate the exit status of a job (aka the Job's `ExitStatus`) is via a `JobExecutionLisener`.  The way you're attempting to manipulate it is using a copy of the real thing.  We do that so that rollback can be implemented cleanly.  You can read more about the `JobExecutionListener` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecutionListener.html

Answer (score 2):

Gotcha!!!

Adding the listener at the job level and then giving a custom EXIT_CODE made it work.

Thanks Michael.

```
public class SampleJobListener implements JobExecutionListener {

@Override
public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
}

@Override
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    // Setting the exception in batch EXIT MESSAGE
    jobExecution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("ERROR","Exception in JOB"));
}
```

}