# How to set ExitStatus of aborted job to "reason for abort" message?

Tags: spring-batch

I need to abort a running job and set its `ExitStatus` to "reason for abort".

It's quite easy to abort a running job:

```java
try {
    if (jobOperator.stop(jobExecutionId)) {
        jobOperator.abandon(jobExecutionId);
        log.info("The job with JobId :" + jobExecutionId + " was canceled.");
    }
}
```

And yes, I know, the only way to set the `ExitStatus` is to use `AfterJob` in `JobExecutionListener` ([Setting EXIT_MESSAGE in batch_job_execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106218/setting-exit-message-in-batch-job-execution))

But how can I transfer "reason for abort" message from the code that abort the job to `JobExecutionListener`'s `AfterJob`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I transfer "reason for abort" message from the code that abort the job to JobExecutionListener's AfterJob?

There is no way to do that. The only information that you can pass from the "outside" (through the job operator) to the "inside" (the job execution and its listeners) is the stop signal.

Everything else can be done on the job execution itself after stopping or aborting it, something like:

```
try {
    if (jobOperator.stop(jobExecutionId)) {
        jobOperator.abandon(jobExecutionId);
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobExplorer.getJobExecution(jobExecutionId);
        jobExecution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("ABORTED", "reason for abort"));
        jobRepository.update(jobExecution);
        log.info("The job with JobId :" + jobExecutionId + " was canceled.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am proud to receive a comment from you, because saw your name many times in spring-batch docs 
Does your explanation mean that there is no way to change the context(s) from the "outside" of a job execution? And the only way to send message to job listeners - set some global (volitile) variable?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the kind words! Always happy to help! `Does your explanation mean that there is no way to change the context(s) from the "outside" of a job execution?`: No, I'm not talking about the execution context, I am talking about the execution itself. There is no programmatic way to influence the execution of a job from the outside other than sending a stop signal. `jobOperator.stop` is the only programmatic way to do that.

Comment: Oh, that means, my initial question was incomplete and inaccurate, sorry for that. I need to stop a running job and set ExitStatus equals to "reason for abort" for it. Being "outside" of execution, I tried to put the reason into ExecutionContext then stop the job execution. Then within AfterJob I got the "reason" from the ExecutionContext . But the "reason" in the ExecutionContext was null.

Comment: `I tried to put the reason into ExecutionContext then stop the job execution`: I would not recommend that. The reason is that, unless you are 100% sure, the job operator could be running in a different thread than the one adding the abortion reason in the execution context. If that is the case, you can end up stopping the job *before* the execution context is updated with the reason, in which case you will get `null` for the reason in the listener.

Comment: `I need to stop a running job and set ExitStatus equals to "reason for abort" for it`: I think the most secure and straightforward way of doing that is as shown in the answer. I see you accepted the answer, so I am glad it helped!